# Dynamic Form with Optional Fields Based on Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question and I searched on how to solve this problem, but I found something easy and similar to what I want, it would be the following:

I need a form where the user to select an option in a combobox form fields change.

eg:
selects option 1
Field 1, Field 2 and Field 3 are displayed to fill
selects option 2
Field 4, Field 5 and Field 6 appear to fill

And when submit identifies himself was filled fields of option 1 or option 2

Sample HTML:

```
<select id="option_selector" name="options">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<div id="options">
    <div id="option1">
        <input type="text" name="input1" value="Input 1" />
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="Input 2" />
        <input type="text" name="input3" value="Input 3" />
    </div>
    <div id="option2">
        <input type="text" name="input4" value="Input 4" />
        <input type="text" name="input5" value="Input 5" />
        <input type="text" name="input6" value="Input 6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know any tutorial or can point me what should I do?

thanks

Comment: combobox => do you mean `<select>`?

Comment: look into the [jQuery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). You should be able to hide the tabs and drive them on select change.

Comment: What did you mean by field and the option? Give some code or example?

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 I assume field = `<input type=text>`. "Input field" is a fairly standard term.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I used the google translator.

what I mean is something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Edumax/HdhuN/2/
In this jsfiddle not displaying a link to hide some fields

Only one link out instead wanted it with a "<select>"
and then filled out the form when the User click confirm, display a popup or some confirmation that he filled the form1 or form2

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did something like this recently at work.  This will do what you want.

I made it so that the name of the select matches up to the id of the option div, and the values of the options match up to the ids of the individual section wrappers.

That way, you could slightly alter it to work with multiple optional-selects on a single page.

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/GUCtC/

```
<select id="option_selector" name="options">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<div id="options">
    <div id="option1">
        <input type="text" name="input1" value="Input 1" />
        <input type="text" name="input2" value="Input 2" />
        <input type="text" name="input3" value="Input 3" />
    </div>
    <div id="option2">
        <input type="text" name="input4" value="Input 4" />
        <input type="text" name="input5" value="Input 5" />
        <input type="text" name="input6" value="Input 6" />
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#option_selector').change(refresh_inputs);
        refresh_inputs();
        function refresh_inputs() {
            var name = $('#option_selector').attr('name');
            var val = $('#option_selector').val();
            $('#'+name+' div').hide();
            $('#'+val).show();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to link the elements this way, but it definitely works.

Comment: don't forget to wrap in a form and add a submit button ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Why not?  I think it's a very graceful way to link the elements together.

Comment: I would assume that the element with ID `#option1` would be the same as `option[value=option1]`

Comment: Why would you ever put an id on an option element?  I've never done so in 15 years in this industry.  Besides which, if your option's id is "option1", just give it a value of "option_div1" and change the id of your div to that.

Comment: `if($("#option1").is(":selected")){...`

Comment: I'm still convinced that this is a good solution, though.

Comment: Fair enough, but again, the names I chose here are for illustration only... they could be whatever OP wants them to be.  The point is that `option.value` = `div.id` is not a conflicting mapping.

Comment: what about `option.id = option.value + "-picker"`?

Comment: I would usually do inheritive ids in such cases.  E.g. `option.id = select.id + '_' + option.value`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20140/discussion-between-thesmose-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: thank you. That was exactly what I had in mind.

Excuse my ignorance (I'm starting now with js), but I would like to identify which div was filled in submit